# HIde word with JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I am not developer so I need help from you guys.

My Problem is simple.

I just want javascript to hide word before  "**.**"

**Example :**

say for **google.com**

I just want word "**.com**" tobe print.

Please note that my content is **dynamic** so **google.com** will keep changing everytime to **google.net** or **yahoo.com**...... so on..

Thanx in advanced.

Comment: I dont quite understand I am not a developer but i need javascript? How do you decide on javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you didn't mention quite a lot, like how do you get your input? What to do if you have no dot, are many dots?
One simple solution is:

```
var s = 'before.after';
var pos = s.indexOf('.');
if(pos >= 0) // here, if I don't find a dot, keep s as it is.
   s = s.slice(pos);

alert(s); // .after
```

Comment: There's also the dark-magic version: `s = s.replace(/^[^.]*/, '');`

Comment: I dont want alert, just need to get it print on page itself

Comment: @manndaar - `alert` is an example. You can use `document.write(s)`, but that isn't best practice. It depends where you want it, how you run the script, and if  you need it more than once. Please add these details to your question.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a tutorial for you on how to parse URL's in Javascript.
http://java-programming.suite101.com/article.cfm/how_to_get_url_parts_in_javascript

Comment: Link-only answers aren't appropriate for SO. By all means reference sources when answering a question, but answer the question within the text of your answer. This keeps SO independent of links that may disappear.

Answer (score 0):

If the content you want to modify is in HTML content, the easiest way is to do string replace.

http://www.bradino.com/javascript/string-replace/

Before using replace, you should first locate the content, by its container ID or Name.

http://www.tizag.com/javascriptT/javascript-getelementbyid.php

http://www.eggheadcafe.com/community/aspnet/3/43154/getelementbyname.aspx

Hope this helps.